# My steering wheel wobbles between 60 - 80 mph

Tags: toyota, tires, camry, wheels, wheel-balance

Car been checked several times at the mechanic's shop, they say can't find the reason.

- Both front axles have been replaced
- I got three sets of rims (Factory 16", Forzas 18" and TIs 20")
- The mechanics blame the tires so that's why I changed them - they all still wobble; the bigger the rims the more I feel it
- All tires have been balanced but the issue is still present

Car is an '04 Camry, thinking of replacing hubs, but when car is jacked up with no tires the hub spins OK

Any advice? I'll appreciate if someone can help me figure out what might be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but is the alignment okay? Have you checked the run-out on the hubs with an indicator? Do the ball joints have excessive play? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTAPRWAE-IU https://tinyurl.com/o3l75en

Comment: I found an a good answer in another thread: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/steering-wheel-shakes-at-high-speeds

Comment: One thing I like to add. Go to a good front end alignment shop. A general mechanic does not have equipment and/or experience in alignment.

Answer (score 3):

few things to check before you go spending too much money

- wheel bearings
- Warped disc brakes
- correctly balanced wheels (sounds oblivious but this used to be the issue 90% of the time when i worked in a garage)
- tracking (as already mentioned)
- bottom arm bushes

after those, things start to get more expensive, its whether the cars worth spending the money on.

Answer (score -1):

You want to lift up the front end and shake the tyres horizontally and vertically. If there are any play, some suspension bushings or steering components need replacing. if there are play in any direction, the hub is bad.

Comment: or ball joint (up/down) or tie rod end(turning left/right)

Comment: Had car re aligned,car at the shop right now :(  roters has been replace, hubs n bearings been check with precision dial everything seems ok, mech dnt know what else to do, car hadnt been in accident or a bad pothole, car could be runjing steady at 65 and shakes n stop shaking and on n on. :( so mad make me wanna let it get repo :'(

Comment: Did you lift car up and grab the wheels and shake up/down and left/right? Mechanics do not want to spend too much time to diagnose because it may take 20 hours to find out problem but customer is not going to pay 20 hours labour. You must shake the wheels.